# Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.(opencv is installed and set opencv4=1)

Tags: c, opencv, yolo, darknet

I am trying to do object detection from a video file by using https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.
I've installed `libopencv-dev` for opencv.
I've set `opencv4=1` in `Makefile`.

And run this code.
`./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo-tiny-obj.cfg yolov3.weights data/1.mp4`
And got error
`Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.`

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to clean make file and recompile darknet

```
make clean
make
```

2. You can load OpenCV from git and install sources

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. 
make -j7
sudo make install
```

And after recompile the darknet with

```
make clean
make
```

Comment: Could you have a look at  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165823/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-20-4) and help me @Viacheslav Popika?